# STL parallel max_element slower that sequential, how to write a better one?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I'm trying to write a parallel version of max_element but works x4 more time than the GCC max_element -fopenmp -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL.

I read the implementation of different STL max_element.
[GCC](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc), [LLVM](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx), [Apache](https://github.com/apache/stdcxx), [The STE||AR Group](https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx), [Electronic Arts](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL), ...

I want to write a function that works differently.
What's the problem? I'm testing it and the parallel version work in more time than the sequential. (test 1 million of uniform_int_distribution uint8_t)

## An Iterative version

So I want to do something like this.

```
template<class RAIt>
  RAIt max_element(RAIt first, RAIt last) {
    size_t threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    size_t bucket_size = (last - first) / threads;
    std::vector<RAIt> local_max( threads );

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads - 1; ++i)
      local_max[i] = std::max_element(first + bucket_size * i, first + bucket_size * (i + 1));

    local_max.back() = std::max_element(first + bucket_size * (threads - 1), last);

    return *std::max_element(local_max.begin(), local_max.end(),
                             [](RAIt left, RAIt right){ return *left < *right;});
  }
```

A good question is:

Why works slower?

Comment: there are two solutions: the for is wrong, or the local_max.back() is wrong. I think the for is wrong. But don't know why.

Comment: Which is the size of your test input ?

Comment: 1 million, but I think I'm wrong the question it's that the test is this: for `for(size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    std::max_element(first, last);`

Comment: and also I create a better sequential version, but... it works slower when.. I that test. if I the values of the vector before every execution of max_element() then works faster. I think will happen the same with the parallel version.

Comment: I try some test but still works slower the parallel.

Comment: Maybe it's your idea... the size, but I have not too much memory to try with more elements.

Comment: What time to you bet for both ? (creating thread, and allocating memory has some overhead, but that overhead should be independent of the size (as its depend of number of threads)).

Comment: yesterday the time was like 3 secs in sequential and 5 in parallel.

Comment: but I add this line and know works in the same time `std::random_shuffle(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector));
    std::max_element(first, last);`

Comment: Just shuffle the vector before use it. In other test I get 0.600 secs, in parallel and 0.070 secs in sequential.

Comment: Google bench mark, says that the sequential version spend the 100% of time in `add    $0x2,%r12` I think was the prediction of the procesor. the one that see that the result was the same a lot of times and say. I don't want work. and just execute de final `add` `it = std::max_element()`